# Theano setting in .theanorc file different beetween gpu and cuda

Tags: gpu, theano, theano-cuda

To configure theano we create a .theanorc file in your home folder and add the following to set up theano to run on GPU.

```
[global]
device = gpu
floatx = float32
```

but sometime i save in configure that smbd put device = cuda, what's the difference?
As i understans, if you use cuda, it should work faster because cuda drivers will manage gpu more better,not getting other jobs for gpu at calculation time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `device=gpu` in your `.theanorc` file instructs Theano to use the `cuda` backend. On the other hand, setting `device=cuda` instructs theano to use the `libgpuarray` backend. Both lead to the use of the GPU (in contrast to setting `device=cpu` in your `.theanorc` file which would lead to the use of the CPU), and the difference is the low-level API they use to communicate with it. The `libgpuarray` backend is the newer one of the two that is a wrapper that allows Theano to communicate with both `cuda` (for NVIDIA GPUs) and `opencl` (for non-NVIDIA GPUs).

Note that the `cuda` backend will be deprecated in the next release of Theano and it is recommended that you always use the `libgpuarray` backend henceforth.